# Node-postgres prepared statements with conditional arguments

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

Is there a way to query something where you hava many conditions that can be undefined (not required)

```
const c = {
  id?: number
  type?: string
}

const sql = `SELECT * FROM smth WHERE id=$1 AND type=$2`

query(sql , [c.id, c.type])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
const sql = `SELECT * FROM smth WHERE ($1::int IS NULL OR id=$1) AND ($2::text IS NULL OR type=$2)`;
```

but in general this is the place where query builder libraries are the appropriate solution.

Comment: hm, i get error: 'could not determine data type of parameter $1'

Comment: @RTW In that case, try with explicit type annotations

Comment: That's correct, but be warned that it may be harder to makes such a statement work efficiently with indexes. Sometimes it will be better to have several prepared statements, one for each case.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks, i think i will just map arguments by hand then

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe You mean the problem is when the query plan is cached between executions with different arguments, where different and more efficient plans would have been found if the `null` value of the argument was known?

Comment: @Bergi No, I meant that it is difficult to index for `12 IS NULL OR id = 12`. Your answer is correct, I just wanted to mention the drawback of having a "universal" prepared statement.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Oh, I had hoped postgres would do some constant folding before selecting an index.

Comment: @Bergi That would happen when the statement is planned. But prepared statements tend to cache plans. I'm not saying it is impossible.